# How to build SQLite with ClearLinux compilation flags?

Tags: sqlite, compilation, archlinux

According to [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=void-linux-2018&num=2) ClearLinux's SQLite is roughly three times faster than ArchLinux-derived distribution one's.

ClearLinux's build script for SQLite is here: https://github.com/clearlinux-pkgs/sqlite-autoconf

When I look at it, PGO is not enabled – I don't see the option which could explain the performance surplus.

So what it the mighty option and how do I port this to [Arch](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/plain/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/sqlite)?